# Hodge variation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, shimura-varieties, hodge-structure

I am reading Milne's online book of Shimura Varieties https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf, I confused by a Definition of Hodge variation. On page 29, it was said something is called Hodge variation if for the $\mathbb{C}$-linear map 
$$
d\varphi_s: T_sS\rightarrow \oplus_p \mathrm{Hom}(F_s^p,V/F_s^p): 
$$
the image is contained in (Griffith transversality)
$$
\oplus_p \mathrm{Hom}(F_s^p,F^{p-1}_s/F_s^p)
$$
Then it is called a variation of Hodge structure on $S$.

Here $V=F^0_s\supset F^1_s\supset\cdots\supset F^p_s\supset\cdots$ is a Hodge Filtration.

[image: See this for original picture]

My problem is, as a variation of a flag $V=V^0\supset V^1\supset\cdots\supset V^n$, (or say the tangent space of flag variety) is described by a compatible families of morphisms $\varphi^i V^i\rightarrow V/V^i$. Compatibility condition is in page 25, equation (17)

$\varphi^i: V^i\rightarrow V/V^i, \quad 1\leq i\leq r$

with compatibility conditions：

$\varphi^i|V^{i+1}\equiv \varphi^{i+1}$ mod $V^{i+1}$

In fact, I was also confused by the above notation so I guess the above notation want to tell me the following commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$

\begin{CD}
V^{i+1} @>\varphi^{i+1}>> V/V^{i+1}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
V^i@>\varphi^i>> V/V^i\\
\end{CD}

The map $\varphi^i$ indicates how the space change, since the change inside $V^i$ is ignored, we only need $V^i\rightarrow V/V^i$ to indicate how it changes. The compatibility condition said as a flag changes, each subspace remain a subspace for bigger subspace, so it can not escape from their parents.

Now, if for all $i$, the image of $\varphi^i$ is contained in $V^{i-1}/V^i$, this implies, $\varphi^{i-1}$ is a zero map, therefore, this indicates only $\varphi^n$ can be non-trivial but other $\varphi^i$ is trivial. But I am sure my understanding is wrong, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand where I was wrong, the image of $\varphi^i$ is contained in $V^{i-1}/V^i$ does not imply $\varphi^{i-1}$ is zero. A good example is

$$
V^0=\mathbb{C}^3, V^1=\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\} 
$$

$$
V^2=\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\} 
$$

Just define $\phi: V\rightarrow V$ to be the one induced by left multiplying the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And let $\varphi^i$ be the restriction of $\phi$ on $V_i$, it is clearly not zero map.

Thanks for all.

Comment: A comment, if the image of $\varphi^i$ is contained in $V_{i-1}/V_i$, this would imply those map can be lifted as $V_{i}/V_{i+1}\rightarrow V_{i-1}/V_i$. Sounds great!